# Can we [tilt] this tag?

Tags: discussion, tags, retag-request, tag-disambiguation

I noticed [tilt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tilt) has questions about tilting things, the development tool [tilt-dev/tilt](https://github.com/tilt-dev/tilt), and also the [Ruby template engine](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt). The tag wiki says it should be used for the Ruby one.

Can we fix this?

- For tilting, the main replacement tag is either [gyroscope](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/gyroscope) or [tilt-sensor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/tilt-sensor) (I'm not really sure the difference between these) or possibly [accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accelerometer).
- I don't use the dev tool so I'm not sure the best name, but some possibilities are [kubernetes-tilt] (as it seems to be a Kubernetes tool) or [tilt-dev] (after the Github owner or their Twitter handle) or [tilt-dev-tilt] (after the name of the GitHub).
- For the Ruby tool, we could make [ruby-tilt]. (I don't use this either, but it seems obvious enough.)

Comment: The actual [tilt] tag wiki states it's [a Ruby templating interface](https://github.com/rtomayko/tilt). I suggest that usage also gets renamed. Would [ruby-tilt] fit?

Comment: @VLAZ Whoops, I thought it was the same as the other tool. I edited to fix that.

Comment: [Tilt], Game Over for this tag.